# Order an SQL Query by literal

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a mysql database, and I have the next query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OP1.meta_value AS meta_value 
FROM  wp_postmeta OP1 WHERE OP1.meta_key like 'size' 
and OP1.meta_value is not null and OP1.meta_value <> 'null' 
ORDER BY OP1.meta_value DESC
```

The results are: small, medium, huge, big,

I need to order this way: small, medium, big, huge...

Is there any solution to order by "literal". 
I think something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OP1.meta_value AS meta_value FROM
wp_postmeta OP1 WHERE OP1.meta_key like 'size' 
and OP1.meta_value is not null 
and OP1.meta_value <> 'null' 
ORDER BY ('small', 'medium', 'big', 'huge')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Incidentally, I suspect that "like 'size'" is the same as "= 'size'", and do you mean NULL or 'null'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    OP1.meta_value AS meta_value 
FROM
    wp_postmeta OP1 
WHERE OP1.meta_key like 'size' 
    and OP1.meta_value is not null 
    and OP1.meta_value <> 'null' 
ORDER BY FIELD (meta_value, 'small', 'medium', 'big', 'huge')
```

Comment: `size` is not a field. You should have used `meta_value`.

Answer (score 1):

The [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function is exactly what you're looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OP1.meta_value AS meta_value FROM
wp_postmeta OP1 WHERE OP1.meta_key like 'size' 
and OP1.meta_value is not null 
and OP1.meta_value <> 'null' 
ORDER BY FIELD (meta_value, 'small', 'medium', 'big', 'huge')
```

BTW, note that using `LIKE` is redundant - since you don't have a wildcard in your search, you can just use `OP1.meta_key = 'size'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT OP1.meta_value AS meta_value FROM
 wp_postmeta OP1 WHERE OP1.meta_key like 'size' 
 and OP1.meta_value is not null 
 and OP1.meta_value <> 'null' 
 ORDER BY (CASE 
    WHEN meta_value='small' THEN 1 
    WHEN meta_value='medium' THEN 2
    WHEN meta_value='big' THEN 3
    WHEN meta_value='hude' THEN 4
END)
```